# fetch different xml views in listview android

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have prepared different xml UI layouts for different components of an android app. Now i need to fetch those different layouts in my list view.

My list view is expandable and each of the item in the list view is different from other items in the list view. For example. i have component1.xml, component2.xml, component3.xml etc as the list item. I need to display these xml files in my list view. How can i do this? I am going crazy over this.

I have fetched similar kind of UI for the list item. But do not have any idea how to Fetch and Display different XML layouts as listitem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try to inflate your required layout according to position in getView() in your adapter..

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom List Adapter and a Custom List Layout

```
package com.fill.in;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;


    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
            List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);

        this.context = context;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtNote;
        TextView txtNoteName;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.note_list_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtNoteName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNoteName);
            holder.txtNote = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNote);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtNoteName.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
        holder.txtNote.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());



        return convertView;
    }



}
```

And the actual Layout File

```
<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txtNoteName"
         android:layout_width="50dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:background="@drawable/note_title_border"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:text="www" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtNote"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:text="wwww" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

and then set it

```
CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(
                    Config.context, R.layout.note_list_layout, list); //the custom adapter notice "R.layout.note_list_layout" which is the xml file above
            lstNotes.setAdapter(adapter); //setting the custom adapter to your listview
```

Answer (score 0):

If every row in your ListView is different I would suggest simply using a vertical LinearLayout within a ScrollView. You will get none of the ListView's optimizations (like view recycling etc) if all your rows are different. Now, if you have several types of rows (which get repeated within your list), then you need to override the [getViewTypeCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) and [getitemViewType(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) methods in your adapter and provide different numbers for different positions. Then, in your getView, you can simply do something like this:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ...
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (type == TYPE_1) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_type_1, null);
    } else if(type == TYPE_2) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_type_2, null);
    } else if(type == TYPE_3) {
    ...
    }
```

And so forth...